# I have to perform inner join operation one two different excel in Automation Anywhere

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I have 2 excel and a list variable which has value which are column header from both excel.
Now I want to make a 3rd excel which should contain the values from 1st and 2nd excel based upon the rule that the list variable columns data should be same in both the excel.

Comment: If you want a `proper` answer, you will need to formulate a `proper` question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a connection string for both the excel. While Executing the SQL statement use the list variable by using F2. You cannot iterate through the select statement in AA.

Answer (score 0):

In AA, you can have a workbook as database and sheets as tables from that database.
So one approach is as:
Let 2 excel workbooks as A and B.

1. Copy data from workbook B to workbook A in sheet2 or any available sheet number.
2. Then, you can have workbook A sheet1 as one table and workbook B sheet2 as another table.
3. Hence, you can have inner join query on two tables from same database with least connection strings.